# Confusing between Thrift API and CQL

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql, astyanax

I am working in a Java web application, using NoSQL (target is Cassandra). I use Astyanax as Cassandra client since it is suggested the best client of Cassandra for now. I've just approached Cassandra for 2 weeks, so many things is so weird to me.
During my working, I encountered some problems and I do not know how to overcome:

1. Is table created from CQL like column family created by Thrift API? I feel they are similar, but maybe there are some differences behind. For example:

   - table create by CQL command cannot be accessed by Thrift API
   - Thrift-based APIs cannot work with tables created by CQL, but CQL methods can access column family created by Thrift API!
2. ​Is primary key in table correspond to row key in column family?
3. In CQL I can declare a table which contains a collection/set/map inside. Can I do the same thing in Thrift API?
4. If my application needs both of them (column families and tables), how can they deal with each other?
5. I recognize one thing: I cannot use Thrift API to do manipulating data on tables create by CQL, and vice versa. I wonder that that, how can I remember which table/column family created from which way so that I can use the correct APIs to process data? For the time being, we don't have a general way to handle two of them, do we? AFAIK, Thrift API and CQL do not have a same interface, so they cannot understand each other?!

Could you please help me explain these things? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes.  It's impossible to update the Thrift APIs to be CQL-aware without breaking existing applications.  So if you use CQL you are committing to using CQL clients only like [the Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver), and not Astyanax, Hector, et al.  But this is no great sacrifice since CQL is much more usable.
2. For a simple PK (i.e., single column), yes.  For a compound PK, [it's a bit more complicated](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts).
3. No.  The Thrift API operates at a lower level, by design.  (So you'd see the individual storage cells that make up the Map, for instance.)
4. I don't understand the question.  With CQL you can do everything you could do with Thrift, but more easily.
5. Simple; don't mix the two.  Stick with one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I believe focus is shifting towards making cassandra look like a RDBMS with SQL Queries to gain wider adoption.
But with inconsistencies between work done using Hector/Astyanax(thrift) and CQL, i think it will hurt adoption. Its almost a U turn from hector/astyanax to CQL in the middle of the journey.

Atleast CQL should have been planned in such a way that Thrift api (and high level java apis on top of it) have no problem in transitioning.